# Como validar um texto (Assert) em determinado campo no Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Como faço para validar um texto em determinado campo?

A localização é xpath:

```
html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/article/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/h1
```

O texto é "*Parabéns! Inserido com sucesso*".

Como devo validar com os assert? Linguagem Java.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa! Segue o código que pode te ajudar:

```
String textoElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/article/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/h1\n")).getText();
        assertEquals("texto-esperado", textoElement);
```